# Showing class not found exception For JSONArray

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
    import org.json.JSONArray;

  JSONArray json=new JSONArray(al);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.getWriter().print(json);
}
```

I have added the jar as well into my project, but it is showing :

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.iqvia.Ajax.GetAutoCompResp] in context with path [/AutoCompleteAjax] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONArray

Comment: As requested I attached the code can you please guide me luk2302

Answer (score 0):

Use method type while making ajax request

eg:

```
$.ajax( {
          url: "/GetAutoCompResp",
          dataType: "json",
          method :"POST",
          data: {
            userId: request.term
          },
          success: function( data ) {
            response( data );
          }
        } );
```

Comment: Hi Arun,

I found the error it is due to the id i am using I named id as userId but i am using userID in ajax call.

Thank you.